# Why doesn't this pymongo subdocument find work?

Tags: mongodb, find, pymongo, subdocument

I'm looking at using mongodb and so far most things that I've tried work. But I don't know why this find doesn't work.

```
col = db.create_collection("test")
x = col.insert_many([
    {"item": "journal", "qty": 25, "size": {"h": 14, "w": 21, "uom": "cm"}, "status": "A"},
    {"item": "notebook", "qty": 50, "size": {"h": 8.5, "w": 11, "uom": "in"}, "status": "A"},
    {"item": "paper", "qty": 100, "size": {"h": 8.5, "w": 11, "uom": "in"}, "status": "D"},
    {"item": "planner", "qty": 75, "size": {"h": 22.85, "w": 30, "uom": "cm"}, "status": "D"},
    {"item": "postcard", "qty": 45, "size": {"h": 10, "w": 15.25, "uom": "cm"}, "status": "A"}
])

cursor = col.find({"size": {"h": 14, "w": 21, "uom": "cm"}})
if cursor.retrieved == 0:
    print("found nothing")          # <<<<<<<<< prints this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking that cursor.retrieved was non zero if it found something. I guess not. I found that this works:

```
lst = list(cursor)
print(lst)

cursor.rewind()
print(list(cursor))

if len(lst) != 0:
    for d in lst:
        print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained into [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/) into section **Match an Embedded/Nested Document**:

> Equality matches on the whole embedded document require an exact match of the specified  document, including the field order.

So, you have to set the object into `find` stage in the same order that exists into DB.

I really don't know if keys into objects follows an strict order (alphabetically or whatever) but using [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nMi2ZjqtBLl) query almost everything output the result. Not always so I think there is a "random" (or not possible to handle) concept to store data -at least into mongo playground-.

By the way, the correct way to ensure results is to use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) so [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L5JBS9M_bnD) query will always works ok.

```
coll.find({
  "size.h": 14,
  "size.w": 21,
  "size.uom": "cm"
})
```

Comment: I looked at those links and tried variations, but still get no results. I guess that I should have said that I'm using pymongo (python). Maybe that makes the diffrence?

Comment: PyMongo works using Mongo under the hook. There is no magic into python code, so Mongo documentation is valid for pymongo.

Comment: cursor = col.find({"size.h": 14, "size.w": 21, "size.uom": "cm"})
I tried this and cursor.retrieved still is zero. If I print the entire collection it is in there.